# Is there a package or library for controlling the DS3231 on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: driver, packages, rtc, timekeeping

I've just obtained a [DS3231 real time clock (RTC)](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DS3231-Real-Time-Clock-RTC-Module-for-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-3-3V-5V-Battery/383739121217), and added it to my **RPi 3b**. It seems to work as far as keeping time, but I wanted *more*.

I'd like to be able to set alarms to trigger the INT/SQW pin on the chip (while retaining the basic timekeeping function I currently have), but I've been unable to find any way to do that with the *toolset* in RPi. I've installed `python-smbus` and `i2c-tools` as part of the RTC configuration. Have I overlooked something? - how should I go about reading & writing the DS3231's internal registers to set up the alarm function on my **RPi 3b**?

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamental choices for working with the DS3231 RTC. One is to write your own code for controlling the DS3231, the other is to use the [DS1307 driver](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.10.y/drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1307.c) included in RPi OS.

If the alarm function is your only requirement (beyond basic timekeeping), the DS1307 driver will meet your needs. This driver is "assigned" to communicate with & control the DS3231 RTC via the `dtoverlay` facility. It is the same `dtoverlay` used for setting up the RTC as a time source - adding the alarm function requires only one additional parameter. Let's cover the specifics:

### Q: How to set an alarm that triggers the INT/SQW pin on the RTC (DS3231)?

As you've already configured the DS3231, and it's keeping time, you're very close to having a functional alarm. In fact, you only need take two additional steps:

#### 1. Add the `wakeup-source` parameter to the `dtoverlay` for `i2c-rtc` in the `/boot/config.txt` file:

***FROM:***   `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231`

***TO:***   `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231,wakeup-source`

Once you reboot your system, the DS1307 driver is prepared to set an alarm.

#### 2. Write the alarm time to the file `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`

As an example, let's assume you want to trigger an alarm 30 minutes from now - here's how to do that:

```bsh
date '+%s' -d '+ 30 minutes' | sudo tee /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

That's all that is needed - the alarm is set. When the alarm *"goes off"* - that is to say when:

> current time = alarm time set in `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`

the RTC will *assert* `INT#` (active low), pulling pin 3 of the DS3231 low. So - pin 3 of the DS3231 may be used as input to a GPIO, or used to trigger some external hardware.

#### 3. Clear/reset the alarm (OPTIONAL)

Depending on your application & requirements, it may be necessary to release the assertion on `INT#` (pin 3 of the DS3231), and allow it to return to its "HIGH" (pulled-up) state. If so (or if you're just tidy), this is easily accomplished by writing a new value to the sysfs. You may write a `0` to simply clear the alarm, or write a future time for the next alarm. For example, to clear the alarm, and de-assert `INT#`:

```bsh
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

### Other alternatives

In the procedure outlined above. the driver does all of the *heavy lifting*. The only code you may need to create is an interrupt handler that defines what action to take when the alarm *"goes off"*, and perhaps clear or reset the alarm. With this approach, you needn't worry about using `python-smbus`, `python-smbus2` or `i2c-tools` to write to the DS3231's internal registers. However, the DS1307 driver - in its present configuration - is incapable of accessing many of the functions and options available in the DS3231 hardware.

You may wish to review the [DS3231 spec sheet](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/real-time-clocks/DS3231.html). Familiarize yourself with its functions and options, and decide if they're worth the extra code-writing effort. If so, you may modify the current driver, and its associated `dtoverlay` - or you may write your own code. This is typically what Arduino users do (they have no driver), and there are libraries available that may be useful. The `i2ctools` suite is another option - [this document](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1092/i2c-part-3---i-c-tools-in-linux) may help.